# Azure DevOps npm build contains files that don't exist locally

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops, kendo-angular-ui

I'm getting these errors during `ng build --environment=sit --aot -ec --output-hashing=media` in Azure DevOps:

[image]

However, when I run the exact same command locally, I get no errors:

[image]

I also noticed the files causing the errors do not exist for me locally.

I'm using node 10.24.1 and npm 6.4.12 (same as DevOps).

**Why do these files not exist for me locally and how can I remove them or fix them in Azure DevOps?**

Here are the dependencies in my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "4.4.6",
"@angular/common": "4.4.6",
"@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
"@angular/core": "4.4.6",
"@angular/forms": "4.4.6",
"@angular/http": "4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.4.6",
"@angular/router": "4.4.6",
"@ngrx/core": "1.2.0",
"@ngrx/store": "2.2.2",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "3.2.4",
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "4.3.3",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "1.4.5",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "3.4.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "2.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "3.12.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "4.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "1.6.1",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "1.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-data-query": "1.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-drawing": "1.5.8",
"@progress/kendo-theme-default": "2.47.0",
"angular-oauth2-oidc": "1.0.20",
"angular2-uuid": "1.1.1",
"angulartics2": "2.5.0",
"core-js": "2.5.1",
"css-element-queries": "0.4.0",
"font-awesome": "4.7.0",
"ifcom": "1.0.30",
"intl": "1.2.5",
"jquery": "3.2.1",
"jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
"lodash": "4.17.5",
"moment": "2.18.1",
"ngrx-store-localstorage": "0.1.8",
"ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.0-beta.8",
"ngx-pagination": "3.0.3",
"pdfjs-dist": "2.0.104",
"rxjs": "5.5.2",
"text-mask-addons": "3.7.1",
"text-mask-core": "5.0.1",
"throttle-debounce": "1.0.1",
"zone.js": "0.8.18"


},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "2.2.1",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.102",
    "@types/node": "8.0.53",
    "angular2-jwt": "0.2.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "browser-sync": "2.26.3",
    "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "karma-teamcity-reporter": "1.0.1",
    "lite-server": "2.3.0",
    "pre-push": "0.1.1",
    "protractor": "5.4.2",
    "sass-lint": "1.12.1",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.8.0",
    "tslint-sonarts": "1.6.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
    "worker-loader": "1.1.0"
  },
```

and here are the @progress dependencies listed in package-lock.json:

```
"@progress/jszip-esm": {
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/jszip-esm/-/jszip-esm-1.0.3.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-qu5qeIlUsJX0Z2oi3Aax3gvfjKrrtVzQ2LIEhmw2CVWffZ0JvtifiomyJOc0ZFk7oEyEyrVvab97bqKkNCKvfQ==",
  "requires": {
    "@progress/pako-esm": "^1.0.1"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": {
  "version": "4.3.3",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-angular-buttons/-/kendo-angular-buttons-4.3.3.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-roJaR/k3EzbynUdFQzkkOyDvD+QKrn5Bc+cG4xNHuEp1S9VVicJDZ5VEsx9JU/zn/cZkr7aUpf0T6Wvtx/7JBg==",
  "requires": {
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-popup-common": "^1.2.3",
    "@telerik/kendo-draggable": "^1.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.7.0"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": {
  "version": "1.4.5",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs/-/kendo-angular-dateinputs-1.4.5.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-DSkW2R1zpfwqTRX0FXPco4oN6BjRo9IAIGKD/fkKyKLp7mUuC/8kJYddQvGiyovDEDyOY0mAqEAmZtGtyF6G6A==",
  "requires": {
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-date-math": "^1.1.0",
    "tslib": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": {
      "version": "1.3.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/-/kendo-angular-popup-1.3.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-IC6Rf71qEzQNjxWgtBSlHhMo00rTBnLRlR/p7scsq6LvswgySX5OcvkdrorDJNnFSmkDxtaeTRTK9Elynikrxg==",
      "requires": {
        "@progress/kendo-popup-common": "^1.2.3",
        "tslib": "^1.7.0"
      }
    }
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": {
  "version": "3.4.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns/-/kendo-angular-dropdowns-3.4.2.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-E11rQ27ANNGHPRaxZsJCvO+IEehGIE0dTOXPtCIdNFlWZ6bO57fWeVMfQLvxMplOGNTvNWQRL+qNxwECBQ68BA==",
  "requires": {
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor": "^3.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-schematics": "^0.2.0",
    "tslib": "^1.7.0"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": {
  "version": "2.3.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export/-/kendo-angular-excel-export-2.3.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-5EKYv8DtZaWhaYoTdGNNasJqwsCuUIHqXmWnnEXxPmKm0mZg3aJk+XFonfeCinx2RzVmxGQb9URH1Q772n2Xbg==",
  "requires": {
    "@progress/kendo-file-saver": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-ooxml": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-schematics": "^0.2.0",
    "tslib": "^1.7.0"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": {
  "version": "3.12.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/-/kendo-angular-grid-3.12.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-4pJBO9EmXuxcRoQbkyyqL9S8CyDnnb3fo/TSZ6eVfpMs5RWOhQa5etB2uRgiIwZ/0qiacgQe3FXm1Tsyajin9Q==",
  "requires": {
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor": "^3.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-file-saver": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-schematics": "^0.2.1",
    "@telerik/kendo-draggable": "^1.9.0",
    "tslib": "^1.7.0"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": {
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/-/kendo-angular-inputs-4.0.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-4mUaT8tzNSVgFDQ/9njuKrGoziws/Q+ZJp9UOmRxEXGEOvR6iJ0b/16A/z/JOqKMcTQLHyYleh5dqtC5nzahPw==",
  "requires": {
    "@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor": "^3.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-common": "^0.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-schematics": "^0.2.0",
    "@telerik/kendo-draggable": "^1.5.1",
    "@telerik/kendo-inputs-common": "^2.2.2",
    "tslib": "^1.7.0"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": {
  "version": "1.6.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-angular-intl/-/kendo-angular-intl-1.6.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-s5p4awEM8hBrmqYFL5O/NLJRbUTaoowzdKVWGNSHHoYSJhbWfCDIEKf+u46EYjDzxu5w0HnijUW+2fqvmRw4YA==",
  "requires": {
    "@telerik/kendo-intl": "^1.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.7.0"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": {
  "version": "1.3.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-angular-l10n/-/kendo-angular-l10n-1.3.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-IoHUXqV+taRx2Bo2qcisBlvXI2IX72Z+69gx8z++VHkG8sccxG7AnuZ7zB/uY31VNhZUh7ZvRbuXx08zFxg8bg==",
  "requires": {
    "tslib": "^1.7.0"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": {
  "version": "1.3.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export/-/kendo-angular-pdf-export-1.3.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-4MbPZItSejzQkbijTzghblTtA6IEJfDuvhy1vJ7IYYRx+6TS6Day+KQODCI30RkCJhApS1j2zX+qfMmlMbPC7A==",
  "requires": {
    "@progress/kendo-file-saver": "^1.0.1",
    "tslib": "^1.7.0"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-angular-popup": {
  "version": "2.6.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-angular-popup/-/kendo-angular-popup-2.6.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-uuewIOhDtE+CaCfVKKR31KkEj/pctzZmbnaIukXu/rnNF+n7ttkwx9/VZFiyuMLbGC1JgiTDXLmY6LavgtdCXQ==",
  "requires": {
    "@progress/kendo-popup-common": "^1.7.0",
    "@progress/kendo-schematics": "^0.2.5",
    "tslib": "^1.7.0"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor": {
  "version": "3.2.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor/-/kendo-angular-resize-sensor-3.2.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-waI9u85A7Qgoa0uOZLoK9azNJAY+p57ua6lV/kITClsIGWGtMU+nxOk87rB2FteB1A7WiAC76xxYgY/fDVAKiA==",
  "requires": {
    "tslib": "^1.7.0"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-common": {
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-common/-/kendo-common-0.1.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-ekEjcFsL3eBHWjh+cO+I/d2RVN7P2pDBI903jmp/dj0ojV3eu+V0u/AYWmvrNEqjeax4sx+qhSnO5iJNB391iQ==",
  "requires": {
    "tslib": "^1.7.0"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-data-query": {
  "version": "1.5.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-data-query/-/kendo-data-query-1.5.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-/uEE+5FUjQ/NGnGPZSr+7lLHN/5QAf9E/tWjLyVuNM/UyLfc9Q8QlLQmEL16ML8FiE0JssgIwbnOtkrSUO6O7Q==",
  "requires": {
    "tslib": "^1.7.0"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-date-math": {
  "version": "1.5.4",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-date-math/-/kendo-date-math-1.5.4.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-Kfg5VSCaDsogW/3h1d/feYDRV7bZki1fvDFX+KkDbi4CE+5Wn0RNZHck6VuqAPWh1x4rjVkBVJHwF2d6H02JyA==",
  "requires": {
    "tslib": "^1.7.0"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-drawing": {
  "version": "1.5.8",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-drawing/-/kendo-drawing-1.5.8.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-eM+8jpH2sR6A7P3DxsdM4hhN+PUraoyVvTIotF9TWdWNnTGejEGgSw5wNGCyWMvxf5Q+9qpBI/rj5djztsiIIw==",
  "requires": {
    "pako": "^1.0.5"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-file-saver": {
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-file-saver/-/kendo-file-saver-1.1.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-26iPl67d0izUlzU6p98QM5f/spOK3QCdmSJrEzGakw1Yp0qyFmp2V9uKeswfWgX0NhKmJApWjlAxxrtRvYjHYA=="
},
"@progress/kendo-ooxml": {
  "version": "1.6.3",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-ooxml/-/kendo-ooxml-1.6.3.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-Rgs0mwNQqxeAow2RFET/tgCvgsl9VlD8lHePuMbUX+o0hdZLaAaSjEatHZPw8zLrqy7ToTa4vi+1wdnsIdMGog==",
  "requires": {
    "@progress/jszip-esm": "^1.0.3",
    "@progress/pako-esm": "^1.0.1"
  }
},
"@progress/kendo-popup-common": {
  "version": "1.8.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-popup-common/-/kendo-popup-common-1.8.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-/cu0nV+3tHKPEE/bUbJTJHv6t8BMYpwI3uVOYENASYy+ZK1dlOfuRhdpSGH85glAH6NMtr/5pYOPojuXFFz/8A=="
},
"@progress/kendo-schematics": {
  "version": "0.2.5",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-schematics/-/kendo-schematics-0.2.5.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-F9ZXPhDoHGQ5MIUTGn7NkEgX5RV6eBfLVtv0yOCKxZpTF6VkYWAnKFYhQFCFgHJsDGPMZtcT2hB1MHntIYIipA=="
},
"@progress/kendo-theme-default": {
  "version": "2.47.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/kendo-theme-default/-/kendo-theme-default-2.47.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-uJlWHDerCTOxzmPXl2skYWJ2Nrc="
},
"@progress/pako-esm": {
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@progress/pako-esm/-/pako-esm-1.0.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-O4A3b1EuE9Xe1pC3Xz9Tcn1M/CYrL71f4y/5TXeytOVTkmkzBgYW97fYP2f+54H0e0erWRaqV/kUUB/a8Uxfbw=="
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by committing package-lock.json (it was untracked).